# String comparison not working with '==' or with php function strcmp

Tags: php, string, select, foreach

In select input field I am selecting value with comparison of strings. But it is not working with string which has `&` character in it. This is the string `Batemans Bay & Eurobodalla` for which `==` is not working. I also tried `strcmp` function but this is also not returning correct value.
This is how my select box look like.

```
<select name="atlas_area_filter" style="width:90%;">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <?php
  $atlas_area_filter = get_option('atlas_area_filter');
  foreach($terms_area as $term_area){
    $term_area_name = $term_area->name;
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $term_area_name; ?>" <?php echo ($term_area_name ==  $atlas_area_filter) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>><?php echo $term_area_name; ?></option>
        <?php
  }
        ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you `echo $atlas_area_filter;`? I suspect you have &amp; instead of & in your string.

Comment: Did you dump both values to see what they actually hold?

Comment: Yes I echo this and it has &. Both strings seems similar but comparison operator is not working for this string.

Comment: Is the first half of the strings mathing? Is the second half of the strings matching?

Answer (score 0):

I mean the problem is parameter encoding. When parameter contain special characters trough by url it automatically encoded.
So try to add `urldecode ( string $str )` function like:

```
$atlas_area_filter = urldecode(get_option('atlas_area_filter'));
```

You can test [here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=464d96fca7e7020bcfbd88d0a4e50cfc&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: I tried to use urldecode but it did not work for me.

Comment: Try to add into your script `var_dump($atlas_area_filter)` may be it have trailing spaces or any other strange characters